# Free abelian groups and lattices

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory

While I was watching some lectures on free abelian groups and lattices, I ran into very confusing moment. Suppose that $V$ is a real vector space with inner product. Obviously,  we can consider $V$ as a metric space as well.

**Definition 1.** Subset $S\subset V$ is called *discrete*, if for any bounded set $B\subset V$ the intersection $B\cap S$ is finite.

Then lecturer mentions that it is equivalent to the following

**Definition 2.** Subset $S\subset V$ is discrete if $\forall x\in S$ $\exists \delta=\delta(x)>0$ such that $N_{\delta}(x)\cap S=\{x\}$, where $N_{\delta}(x)$ is a ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $x$.

Then proves the following

**Theorem:** Any additive discrete subgroup $L$ of $V$ is free and any basis of $L$ is linearly independent in $V$.

I have two question:

1. The definition of discrete set given in Definition 1 is not equivalent to the regular one which I provided. Just consider the set $\{1/n\}_{n\geq 1}$ because it is discrete in the sense of regular definition but does not satisfy to Definition 1. Am I missing something here?
2. When he starts to prove Theorem he assume that $\text{span}(L)=V$. Why does he do that? Can anyone explain it?

Thank you!

Comment: For 2, you can replace $V$ with the span and proceed, so you may as well assume the span *is* $V$. Not sure about 1 because it requires more context for the given definition.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Thank you! In that case probably I need to add the proof of Theorem.

Comment: For subgroups both definitions of discreteness are equivalent. By the way, I think you forgot to assume that $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, yes, $V$ is finite-dimensional. I am wondering can you show the proof why for subgroups both equivalent? At least, I know that in general Definition 2 implies Definition 1.

Comment: The two definitions are equivalent if you assume that $S$ is a closed set, or if you assume that $S$ is a subgroup of $V$. Without further hypothesis the two definitions are not equivalent, as you say, because $S=\{ 1 /n : n \ge 1 \}$ provides a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

1. Under the assumption that $S$ is a subgroup of $V$ the two definitions are equivalent. A proof follows:

*definition 1 implies definition 2*: for all $x \in S$, the ball $N_1(x) \cap S$ is a finite set. Let $\delta = \frac{1}{2} \min \{ |x-y| : y \in N_1(x) \cap S ; \quad y \neq x\}$. Then $N_\delta (x) \cap S = \{ x\}$.

*definition 2 implies definition 1*: $S$ is a subgroup of $V$, hence $0 \in S$. By definition 2 there exists $\delta >0$ such that $N_\delta(0) \cap S = \{ 0\}$.
Let $B$ be any bounded subset of $V$. We want to show that $B \cap S$ is finite. Here it comes the hypothesis that $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space: since $B \cap S$ is bounded, then it is totally bounded. In other words it can be covered by finitely many balls of radius $\delta$. Call such family $$N_\delta (x_1), \dots, N_\delta (x_n)$$ where the $x_1, \dots, x_n \in B \cap S$. We show that $B \cap S \subseteq \{ x_1, \dots , x_n\}$ which implies that it is a finite set. $\forall y \in B \cap S$ there exists $i$ such that $y \in N_\delta (x_i)$. Then $|y-x_i| < \delta$ and $y -x_i \in S$ because $S$ is a subgroup of $V$. Hence $$y - x_i \in N_\delta (0) \cap S = \{ 0\}$$
This means that $y=x_i$. By arbitrarity of $y \in B \cap S$ we have the desired inclusion $B \cap S \subseteq \{ x_1, \dots , x_n\}$.

Note that this proof does not work for vector spaces of infinite dimensions: in such spaces we could build a counterexample.

2. A similar proof can be written in the case when $S$ is closed subset of $V$. Here the proof relies on compactness arguments (closed and bounded means compact).

*definition 1 implies definition 2*: same as before.

*definition 2 implies definition 1*: Let $B$ be any bounded subset of $V$. We want to show that $B \cap S$ is finite. Without loss of generality we can suppose that $B$ is closed, otherwise argue the following with $\overline{B}$ (the closure of $B$).
Since both $B$ and $S$ are closed, the intersection $B \cap S$ is closed and bounded. Hence it is compact.
By hypothesis for all $x \in B \cap S$ there exists a ball of radius $\delta = \delta(x)$ centered at $x$ such that
$$N_\delta (x) \cap S = \{ x\}$$

Hence tha family of balls $\{ N_{\delta(x)} (x) | x \in B \cap S\}$ is an open cover of $B \cap S$. Since $B \cap S$ is compact, it can be covered by finitely many such balls, say
$$N_{\delta(x_1)} (x_1), \dots, N_{\delta(x_n)} (x_n)$$
This implies that $B \cap S = \{ x_1, \dots, x_n\}$, and so it is a finite set.